# Multiplicative inverse of polynomial modulus an integer

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

How do you calculate the multiplicative inverse of a polynomial mod a monomial/integer?The specific questions are:
Find the multiplicative inverse of
1) x+1 mod 3
2) x^2+x-1 mod 3
3) x^2+x-1 mod 32

I understand that you need to use the Extended Euclidean algorithm to solve it. For integer mod integer (e.g. 11 mod 26) and polynomial mod polynomial, its clear.But how to solve x+1 mod 3?

Answer (score 1):

Neither $x+1$ nor $x^2+x-1$ are invertible modulo $3$, i.e. in the polynomial ring $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[x]$, which is a polynomial ring over a field, because in such a case, for any polynomials $f,g$ we have $\deg fg=\deg f+\deg g \ge\deg f,\deg g$, which is not compatible with $fg=1$ unless $f$ and $g$ are constants.

If the quotient ring is not a field, this may not be true. However $x^2+x-1$ invertible in ,is impossible  since its leading coefficient is $1$, hence $\deg f(x)(x^2+x-1)=\deg f+2$.

For an example with coefficients in  $\mathbf Z/32\mathbf Z$ you can check  that $\;(16x^2-4x+1)(4x+1)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: do you mean that for a polynomial `f` to have a multiplicative inverse `mod g` then inline`deg fg=deg f+deg g ≥deg f,deg g` ? If that is the case then `x+1 mod 3` meets the criteria because `deg ((x+1)3)=1' and `deg f=1` and `deg g=0` . Kindly explain

Comment: If $fg=1$, we must have $\deg f+\deg g=\deg 1=0$, whence $\deg f=\deg g=0$, i. e. $f$ and $g$ must be non-zero constants.